# Why am I getting SAS ERROR 22-322 syntax error

Tags: sas, syntax-error

My codes are as below, the problem comes from codes after the note /*now you can apply your logic to the dataset*/, the problem in the log is **Testwyf..** and **ERROR 22-322: syntax error**, I don't know why there are two dots, and I want to make it like **libname.memname**, but it just doesn't work.
Hoping someone could help me solve this problem.

input dataset Testwyf.varlst:

[image]

### Error update:
[image]

Error:

MPRINT(LOOPOVERDATASETS):   data Testwyf."           ."N(drop=TradingTime);

NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "INDSN".

1     .."           ."N
-
22
200
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJske.png)

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, ;, CUROBS, END, INDSNAME, KEY, KEYRESET,
KEYS, NOBS, OPEN, POINT, *DATA*, *LAST*, *NULL*.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

```
%macro loopOverDatasets();
/*imho good practice to declare macro variables of a macro locally*/
%local datasetCount iter inLibref inMember outLibref;

/*get number of datasets*/
proc sql noprint;
    select count(*)
     into :datasetCount
    from Testwyf.Varlst;
quit;

/*initiate loop*/
%let iter=1;
%do %while (&iter.<= &datasetCount.);
    /*get libref and dataset name for dataset you will work on during this iteration*/
    data _NULL_;
        set Testwyf.Varlst (firstobs=&iter. obs=&iter.); *only read 1 record;
        *write the libname and dataset name to the macro variables;
        call symputx("inLibref",strip(libname));
        call symputx("inMember",nliteral(memname));
        call symputx("outLibref","Testwyf");

        *NOTE: i am always mortified by the chance of trailing blanks torpedoing my code, hence the strip function;
    run;

    /*now you can apply your logic to the dataset*/
    %let indsn = &inLibref..&inMember.;
    %let outdsn = &outLibref..&inMember.;
    data &outdsn.(drop=TradingTime);
    set &indsn.(keep=Symbol ShortName TradingTime LastPrice OpenPrice);
    Date=put(TradingTime,DATETIME15.);
    run;



    /*** ANY OTHER PROCS/DATA STEPS ***/
    /*just remember to use &inLibref..&inMember. to refer to the current dataset*/

    /*increment the iterator of the loop*/
    %let iter=%eval(&iter.+1);
%end;
%mend;

/*call the macro*/
%loopOverDatasets()
```

Comment: Use the modern CALL SYMPUTX() instead of the ancient CALL SYMPUT() if you don't want to write leading/trailing spaces into your macro variables.

Comment: Why are you incrementing your own do loop counter instead of just use `%do iter=1 %to  &datasetCount.;`

Comment: Turn on MPRINT and show an example of SAS statement that the rmacro  generates that is being tagged with that error code.

Comment: What setting do you have for VALIDVARNAME option? Are any of your member names non-standard names?

Comment: You appear to have not only a missing value for the variable MEMBER in your source dataset, but it kind of looks like it is a numeric variable instead of character variable. What is the source of this list of datasets? The normal SAS metadata will use MEMNAME not MEMBER as the name for that variable.

Comment: If the data does not have the libref (value of LIBNAME variable) then just hard code the libref in the code.

Comment: Why are you writing macro code at all if you only have three datasets to process.  Just copy and paste the code and manually change the dataset name.

Answer (score 2):

Your updated information shows that you have observations in your input dataset Testwyf.Varlst with empty values of LIBNAME and MEMBER.  Also having a period in the value of MEMBER is probably indication that it is either a numeric variable (or does not even exist in that dataset) or was generated from a numeric variable that had a missing value.  So fix your input dataset.

Sometimes the macro processor interferes with SAS's ability to parse your code into tokens for evaluation and a single token that it being built with macro code is seen as two tokens instead of one.  One simple solution is to build the token into another macro variable and then use that macro variable to generate the code.

In your case make macro variables to hold the full dataset names and then use those to generate the SAS code.

```
%let indsn = &inLibref..&inMember.;
%let outdsn = &outLibref..&inMember.;
data &outdsn.(drop=TradingTime);
  set &indsn.(keep=Symbol ShortName TradingTime LastPrice OpenPrice);
```

Also protect yourself from non-standard member names.

```
call symputx("inMember",nliteral(memname));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the error still exists and is still the same error

Comment: Turn on MPRINT option and edit your quesiton to include the lines of generated SAS code that cause the error message.

Comment: The edit has been made

Comment: Check the input dataset with the list of members. Are there empty values? Are you using the right variable name in your code?

Comment: I checked the input dataset and put the screenshot above, it seems that there is no empty values

Comment: I think something is wrong with call symputx("inMember",nliteral(member)); part, and the member cannot be captured correctly

Comment: I checked the format by checking column attributes, it appears to be format "$32. , and type character

Comment: Are you sure it is `member` and not `memname`?

Comment: Thank you Joe, I tried memname and it seems that the capture part is fixed. However, the original problem still exits

Comment: I update my new error above.

Comment: Is the `libname` variable defined?  Doesn't look like it... You really need to do some just basic debugging here, this isn't StackOverflow material right now I don't think.

Comment: Thank you, but why libname variable needs to be defined? Isn't it already defined in the "user" lib which is one of the system lib?

Comment: If you use just a one level name then the default libref that SAS will use is WORK.  But if you **have** defined a libref named USER it will be using instead of WORK, but most programmers do not define a USER libref, . We cannot see your environment so do not know where your datasets names are or what librefs you have defined or where the datasets are that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tom's generally right for finding the problem with this macro, so I'll suggest a totally different approach.  `%do` loops are hard to troubleshoot, because the macro language isn't as good at logging errors.

Instead, my preferred approach is to do this as separate units.

1. Write a macro that does what you want done, once.
2. Write code that calls that macro once for each row in your dataset.

(1) is easy to do, hopefully.  It's just the last part of your code.

(2) has a lot of different approaches, all of which are fine, depending on some details.  If you're doing a reasonably small number of these, then the best approach in my opinion is `proc sql select into`, with the caveat that it has two majors issues: if there is a `call execute` up the line of it, you might not have the results you expect; and there is a 64000 character limit to the text of the `select into`, so if you have a lot of observations (or a smaller lot of very long calls) it can run into trouble.  But if you're running this for a few hundred observations, you're probably cool doing it this way.

Here's one example of how to do this.  Feel free to read my paper [Writing Code With Your Data](https://github.com/snoopy369/presentations/tree/master/Writing%20Code%20With%20Your%20Data) for a more detailed take on this.

```
*First, set up example dataset;
data change;
  length var $32 expr $1024;
  dataset='sashelp.class';
  outset='class';
  var='bmi';
  expr='703*weight/(height**2)';
  output;
  dataset='sashelp.cars';
  outset='cars';
  var='mpg_avg';
  expr='mean(mpg_city,mpg_highway)';
  output;
run;
  
  
*Here, define the macro that will be run on each row of the dataset;
%macro change_ds(dataset=, outset=, var=, expr=);
  data &outset;
    set &dataset;
    &var. = &expr. ;
  run;
%mend change_ds;


*Now, use PROC SQL to select the macro calls into a macro variable;
*I leave off NOPRINT because I like to see the list in the results, but you can add it for production if you want;
proc sql;
  select cats('%change_ds(dataset=',dataset,',outset=',outset,',var=',var,',expr=%nrstr(',expr,'))')
    into :runlist separated by ' '
    from change
    where not missing(dataset) and not missing(outset) and not missing(var) and not missing(expr);
quit;


*Now, run it.  Add the symbolgen/mprint options if it is helpful for debugging;
options symbolgen mprint;

&runlist.;

*Note, the semicolon above is not needed - I always include it to fix the syntax highlighting, but make sure you know it is not useful;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try your code later, but the problem still exits right now

Comment: I update the error above

Comment: Sorry for letting you think this problem is valueless, but I still don't know how to solve the problem and I don't understand why I need to define the libname... I am new to sas and I have just study it for 3-5 days, so I hope maybe you could give me some suggestions like how to solve this problem, or where could I find the answer.. Thank you.

Comment: The point is that StackOverflow isn't for this kind of thing: iterative debugging help.  You got the correct answer early on (from Tom) and another way of doing it (from me), but now you're going through it bit by bit constantly changing things - so the initial answer by Tom isn't even accurate anymore.  That's not what StackExchange is for.  Ask your manager for help, or spend some more time learning SAS - your issue isn't a programming problem, it's that you're working with code several levels above what a 3-5 day old SAS programmer should be working with.

Comment: Ok I get it.. I don't have a manager and I am currently working on a paper nearly by myself. I used to use Python but the dataset is too large. I don't have a familiar instructor to help me out here.. But thank you for your advice, I will try StackExchange for help or study for more time